# “pdo_mysql” is disabled and I can't get it enabled. I have MAMP v. 3.0.4 installed on my iMac 7.1 OSX 10.6.8

Tags: php, mysql, macos, pdo, mamp

“pdo_mysql” is disabled and I can't get it enabled. I have MAMP v. 3.0.4 installed on my iMac 7.1 OSX 10.6.8. On my phpinfo page I can see that the only PDO enabled is sqlite. If I look in my php (5.5.10) extensions folder I do see the pdo_mysql.so file (as well as one ending with .a). But if I go to the php.ini file the both the extensions folder path and the extension=pdo_mysql.so are there and correct. It feels like maybe my Mac is using another php.ini file but how do I find that out? Does anyone have any tips on how I can get the PDO enabled?

Comment: what do you have about your pdo when your run `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Do `php --ini` to see the ini files used, do `php -m` to see all modules loaded. (Note this is what applies to the CLI version, usually the files used should be the same). Or do `phpinfo();` in a script file.

Comment: When I do phpinfo(); I get two boxes. One title PDO that lists PDO drivers and only shows sqlite (enabled). The second box is titled pdo_sqlite and lists SQLite Library as 3.7.7.1 (enabled). That is all I get.

Comment: When I put php --ini in my terminal I get: Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
When I put php -m in my terminal I get:[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
soap
sockets
SPL
SQLite
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
plus some...

Comment: So from php --ini it looks like it is using another file for the php.ini and not the one in the MAMP folder. I did look for a folder called etc (found in HD/private/etc) and in there I find three php.ini files (php.ini-5.2-previous, php.ini.default and php.ini.default-5.2-previous). I went in and added the extensions folder path in MAMP and made sure extension=pdo_mysql.so was there. But nothing changed in the phpinfo(). Do you recommend I try it in the other two? There must be some easier way to be sure which php.ini I should be working in... Help!

Comment: From the php -m it looks like pdo_mysql is there, but clearly php.ini does not see it. Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks to both Lukas and Notulysses for your comments, it's leading me one step closer to solving this.

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling with this the whole weekend and finally solved it. Turns out that the php.ini is pointing to a non-existing "extensions dir". Create a phpinfo() file and look at the value of this field:
[image: extensions_dir]

I noticed that in the mamp php installed folder there is a no-debug-non-zts-20131226 folder, which is different from the value shown in the phpinfo(). What I did was to clone this folder and changed the name to the value of the phpinfo(). Probably you could modify the php.ini file but I didn't want to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This problem applies to php 5.6 version too.

Comment: @jesusbet I think I have same issue as you. I don't understand what you mean by "php installed folder". My phpinfo shows same extension dir as your screenshot and that folder has the right contents. I don't see a no-debug folder anywhere else on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using PHP 5.4 but the value in the php.ini was pointing to the extensions folder of PHP 5.5. I simply changed the php.ini settings and restarted MAMP.

php.ini

```
extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.34/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-201005‌​25"
```