# Why doesn't PHP see MAMP's MySQL PDO driver?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mamp

Out of the box I only see `sqlite` under PDO drivers from `phpinfo()`.

I saw the extensions folder is correct which has `pdo_mysql.so`.

My `php.ini` has: `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

Not sure why PHP is only registering the one driver.

Meanwhile I know the MySQL server is running fine via MAMP by connecting in workbench.

This is all in PHP 5.6.2.

**EDIT**

So I have PHP installed from default on my Mac. I also have MAMP which puts PHP in a different location.
For example php -v will give me 5.4, for the default location. MAMPs php is elsewhere and on the more recent version.

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php -v` gives 5.6.2
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php -m | grep pdo` gives:

```
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
```

Here is a screenshot of my phpinfo just for sanity's sake

[image: phpinfo PDO]

**EDIT 2**

Seems related to [“pdo_mysql” is disabled and I can't get it enabled. I have MAMP v. 3.0.4 installed on my iMac 7.1 OSX 10.6.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377883/pdo-mysql-is-disabled-and-i-cant-get-it-enabled-i-have-mamp-v-3-0-4-install) but I can't find the duplicate folder this user talks about

**EDIT 3**

This dialog wasn't lying. Using the trial for Pro fixed this "issue". However deleting Pro and launching MAMP still failed. Clearly an issue with MAMP. Opened a support ticket with them and I'll write here when I get an answer of sorts

[image]

Comment: In a terminal, what does `php -m | findstr pdo` give you (`php -m | grep pdo` on OSX)?

Comment: I cannot recreate this in the latest version of [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/). These extensions are installed.

Comment: @JacobBudin Any idea what could cause a disconnect between php.ini and runtime?

Comment: @DaveStein Did you previously modify the `php.ini` or is this a fresh MAMP install?

Comment: It's fresh. The only weird thing I can think of is that I updated php on my machine before getting MAMP, but it's two different installs and phpinfo is pointing at the right place for everything.

Comment: @JacobBudin Version 3.0.7.3 (3.0.7.3), seems to be the latest.