# MAMP 3.1 and MySQL PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo, mamp, mamp-pro, mysqlnd

I just grabbed the latest version of MAMP Pro (3.1) and installed it only to find that it removes MySQL PDO entirely. That's a problem since the framework I'm using requires PDO to connect to the database. I tried grabbing the extensions from the old version of MAMP, but it immediately throws errors.

How do I get MySQL PDO back for MAMP 3.1? I've looked on the site and can't find a downloads page to roll back to the older version.

Comment: mamp should have its own copy of pdo, you might just have to enable/install it. and no, grabbing copies of the libs from older versions is pointless. "My fancy aluminum baseball bat is broken, so I grabbed this stone age wooden club. they're both bats, why isn't it working?"

Comment: No, it only includes the Postgres PDO extension. No MySQL PDO extension at all.

Answer (score 1):

In MAMP 3.1, they've made the switch to `mysqlnd` which actually includes mysql, mysqli, and PDO. The problem is that they've removed all the PDO settings in `php.ini` because they aren't using the MySQL PDO extension. Because of this change, from the command line, PHP is looking at the wrong MySQL socket file. To fix this, I updated the `php.ini` file with the following line:

`pdo_mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

After that, everything started working again.

If anyone from Appsolute sees this, PLEASE re-add the PDO settings to the INI files so this sort of thing doesn't happen!

Comment: Strange because my Mamp Pro 3.1 php.ini file has this line by default... `[PDO] pdo_mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` And my PDO is working fine. I just bought it yesterday so i did no update or whatever.

Comment: We have just updated to 3.1 from 3.0.5 and we are getting PDO errors. Our `php.ini` already has the `pdo_mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` line set by default.

Not found a solution yet, had to revert back to 3.0.5

Comment: @Peter Mine didn't actually have that line, which is what was causing the issue since it was looking at the wrong .sock file. I only figured that out because I ran a `php -i | grep pdo` and saw the wrong file referenced in the output. Not sure why mine had issues and yours didn't though. Strange.

Comment: indeed strange! It isn't answered but i think this is in a way related to this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792878/why-doesnt-php-see-mamps-mysql-pdo-driver. Could be something that happens while you install MAMP? Maybe it happened in your situation and not in mine?

Comment: FYI you need to use "php -i|grep php.ini" to find the php.ini file it's using.